# TYPO3 website migration issue - the TYPO3 backend works but the frontend doesn't work

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, access-rights

I am trying to migrate a TYPO3 website from one web host to another. The site is using TYPO3 version 6.2.10.

I am following the steps provided here - https://blog.scwebs.in/how-to-transfer-typo3-site-to-a-new-host/

I can log into the backend of the site. which is here and can see the list of all pages under the page section. http://79.170.40.34/historylearning.com/typo3/

[image]

But the front end is broken. http://79.170.40.34/historylearning.com/index.php

Can you please suggest any solution.

Additional Note -

1. In this [link](https://blog.scwebs.in/how-to-transfer-typo3-site-to-a-new-host/) it has suggested to upload these folders /fileadmin; /t3lib; /typo3; /typo3conf; /typo3temp; /uploads; .htaccess; index.php. But I don't have the /t3lib folder inside the site content
2. the above [link](https://blog.scwebs.in/how-to-transfer-typo3-site-to-a-new-host/) also suggested

> When the files are all uploaded, you will need to change the
> permissions recursively for /fileadmin, /typo3conf, /typo3temp,
> /uploads, and index.php to chmod 777.

But If I set the permission to 777 then I cannot access it at all. So I have left it to default permission of 755

3. On the same [Link](https://blog.scwebs.in/how-to-transfer-typo3-site-to-a-new-host/) In step 20 it has suggested

> Click on “Templavoila” and then “Update mapping”

I cannot find that option anywhere.

4. During the time of installation, I see this error. I don't quite understand what this means

[image]

Is it the reason? if so how to resolve this issue.

I do not have any previous experience with TYPO3. Please suggest a solution. My server environment is Linux.

Comment: The symlinks thing is **not** a problem here. Very first issue to fix: your project initially is placed in `http://79.170.40.34/historylearning.com/` location, so trying to use paths like `/fileadmin/style.css` will try to find it starting from `http://79.170.40.34/` point. Use base URL, to inform the browser, that you're staring in the subfolder called `historylearning.com` or (definitely better) move project files one level higher or use subdomain so root will bei.e. at: `http://history.79.170.40.34`

Comment: (*continue*) take a look the CSS is available at `http://79.170.40.34/historylearning.com/fileadmin/template/2.8/docs61.css` but browser looks for it at`http://79.170.40.34/fileadmin/template/2.8/docs61.css`. Refactoring file structures, or creating VHOST pointing to the `historylearning.com` subfolder as a root of the project will fix this issue. Please fix it hen let us know, most probably next thing to fix will be url rewriting (.htacccess/mod_rewrite), but I don't wonna to guess

Comment: @biesior- Is that mean if I forward the domain to my new host then the problem will be gone?

Comment: Can not say that for 100%, but as already mentioned using subfolder as a root of the project is one of the detected problems. Without solving it you will not be able to go further. Tip: you don't need to redirect/forward your domain just for testing. Just you can modify the `hosts` file to make your local computer thinking that the domains point to your `79.170.40.34` server. Depending on the OS you are using Google for file location and ways to edit it. Don't forget to flush the DNS cache on your comp after changes in this file.

Comment: Just in your `hosts` add this line:  `79.170.40.34 historylearning.com` and flush DNS, so your browser will lookup for the domain with new IP (for other users it will be unchanged), then make sure that at new server VHOST points directly to `historylearing.com` folder (not one folder above as you have it now) and more or less it should start work - at least paths to assets like CSS/JS/images will be valid. Currently your vhost points to folder on the server like (just guessing) `/www/sites/project1/` and should be `/www/sites/project1/historylearning.com/`

Answer (score 1):

As your referenced page mentioned to copy `t3lib` it shows that it's very old. the folder got removed long time ago.

Your installation with TYPO3 6.2 also is very old and should not get in production any more. But it could be a base for an update to TYPO3 10LTS (don't use 9LTS as it will end support in octobre), although it is a long way.

Your file access rights on the server should enable you and your web-server to access the files. The most commonly used solution: you and your web-server-user (something like: `apache`,`www`, `wwwrun`,..) have a common group and the group-owner of all is set to this common group.
And then the access mask is set to 775 (better 2775 so access is inherited) for folders and 664 for files.

```sh
chown youraccount:www -R * 
find . -type d -exec chmod 2775 "{}" \; 
find . -type f -exec chmod g+w "{}" \;
```

if you have copied the files with your account and use only 755 rights for folders TYPO3 can not work correct and it will result in an incomplete website.

`templavoila` is an extension which was used not for every installation. Be happy if your installation has no `templavoila`

Comment: Your file access rights on the server should enable you and your web-server to access the files. The most commonly used solution: you and your web-server-user (something like: apache,www, wwwrun,..) have a common group and the group-owner of all is set to this common group.
And then the access mask is set to 775 (better 2775 so access is inherited) for folders and 664 for files.
-- Can you please explain this paragraph with little bit more detail please. I do not understand system administration much

Comment: @Bernd, OP just messed up with paths, pls see my comments to the question. Of course, updating it to at least 10LTS is the most desired solution, but first it can be run as it is, just with several simple fixes (if no other conflicts occurs)

Comment: he states using 6.2.10 which is far from the last public free available version. which means it is very insecure. there was an ELTS program to get further security fixes. There were some fixes, which means the latest public version still is insecure.

Answer (score 0):

TYPO3 6.2.x is not supported anymore, you should not use this version in production because it could contain vulnerabilities that threaten the security of your host system.

When I load your website I see lots of missing ressources in the network tab of the developer tools (hit <kbd>F12</kbd>), e.g.

```
GET http://79.170.40.34/typo3temp/stylesheet_5a17574694.css
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 31ms]
GET http://79.170.40.34/fileadmin/template/2.8/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 80ms]
GET http://79.170.40.34/fileadmin/template/2.8/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 84ms]
GET http://79.170.40.34/fileadmin/template/2.8/docs61.css
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 79ms]
GET http://79.170.40.34/fileadmin/template/2.8/History-Learning-Logo.png
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 148ms]
GET http://79.170.40.34/fileadmin/historyLearningSite/roman_9.jpg
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 116ms]
GET http://79.170.40.34/fileadmin/historyLearningSite/will1.6.jpg
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 80ms]
GET http://79.170.40.34/uploads/pics/H8ii-front.jpg
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 80ms]
GET http://79.170.40.34/fileadmin/historyLearningSite/gunpow1.gif
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 79ms]
GET http://79.170.40.34/fileadmin/historyLearningSite/domest1.gif
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 111ms]
GET http://79.170.40.34/fileadmin/historyLearningSite/infant2.jpg
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 75ms]
GET http://79.170.40.34/fileadmin/historyLearningSite/derby_2.jpg
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 73ms]
```

Make sure to copy all files from the fileadmin folder of your old host to the new one and check if things get better.

Comment: fact that the files are not available is **not** caused by old version (although I agree it dederves update to some newer LTS)/ Sorry this answer will be marked as a not-an-answer.